# Postgres usuário com acesso apenas na replica

Tags: postgresql, permissões, replicação

O banco em questão possui replicação de dados, o mesmo banco, porem em outro servidor, tem como garantir o acesso de um usuário ( user_bi ) apenas na réplica ?

```
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM user_bi;
```

Isto revoga as permissões do banco, mas revoga também as permissões da replica, tem como permitir acesso a um e não a outro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontramos foi limitar o acesso por ip no pg_hba.conf.